# Run my WinForms project using a SQL Server database on another PC

Tags: sql-server, database, winforms, sql-server-2019

I wanted to run my WinForms project (that includes working with a SQL Server database and that worked perfectly on my PC) on another PC.

I made a Registration Form App and when I run it on another PC error 26 shows

> Error Locating Server/Instance Specified.

Comment: Did you first install SQL Server 2019 on that other PC ? If you're using SQL Server as your database, you must have SQL Server installed - either locally on the machine running your app, or somewhere in the network so you can reach the database

Comment: Oh no i did not install